# Add html content using jQuery after method or another

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to add html content to my page after certain div element using jquery. It will be several lines of code. I was playing with the scripts below. The script with p element works, and second one doesn't. Why is that and how do I make it work with any html content?

```
<script> 
$(".myClass").after("<p>text</p>");
</script>

<script> 
$(".myClass").after("<div><img src="http://example.com/image.png"></div>");
</script>
```

Comment: hi use single quotes .after('html here')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
$(".myclass").after("<div><img src='http://example.com/image.png'></div>");
```

use double quote only one time and you can use single quote multiple times

Comment: please upvote the answet if it helped you @qwe so it can help others too

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using quotes inside quote, the string is break and you get syntax error.

To fix this, you can escape the quotes by preceding it with `\`.

```
$(".myClass").after("<div><img src=\"http://example.com/image.png\"></div>");
//                                 ^^                            ^^
```

Or you can use single quote inside double quotes and vice versa.

```
$(".myClass").after('<div><img src="http://example.com/image.png"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just replace your existing scripting code with this one:
  <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
               $(".myClass").after("<p>text</p>");
               $(".myClass").after("<div><img src=\"http://example.com/image.png\">
        });
  </script>
```